# const before AND after function

Tags: c++, constants

I am working on a class project and my teacher has given us functions that we must write. Here is an example of one. I am wondering why there is a const at the beginning and the end. What do they do that they are needed on either end?

```
const Foo multiple(int value) const;
```

Comment: take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness

Answer (score 5):

The first *const* applies to the return type of the member function.

The second *const* applies to the invisible *this* argument that is a pointer to the instance calling the Foo method.

Answer (score 2):

First one is the type of the return value (`const Foo`), the second one means that it doesn't alter the class.